# Why was there a temporary 8% spike in the total price of the Steam store during April 13-16, 2019?

Tags: steam

According to [this website](https://steam.seewang.me/) (which has been cited on [Kotaku](https://kotaku.com/it-would-cost-538-000-to-buy-everything-on-steam-1845044276) [and](https://www.techspot.com/news/86736-would-cost-over-half-million-dollars-buy-everything.html) [elsewhere](https://www.gamebyte.com/this-is-how-much-itd-cost-to-buy-every-single-game-on-steam/)), there was an 8% spike in the total price of the Steam store during April 13-16, 2019:

[image: graph of Steam store price history]

```
[
  {
    "original": "401,924.59",
    "sale": "394,678.93",
    "cc": "US",
    "language": "English",
    "created_at": "2019-04-17T00:26:52.000000Z"
  },
  {
    "original": "434,284.01",
    "sale": "427,579.42",
    "cc": "US",
    "language": "English",
    "created_at": "2019-04-16T00:27:40.000000Z"
  },
  {
    "original": "434,429.95",
    "sale": "428,869.95",
    "cc": "US",
    "language": "English",
    "created_at": "2019-04-15T00:27:45.000000Z"
  },
  {
    "original": "434,410.97",
    "sale": "428,657.58",
    "cc": "US",
    "language": "English",
    "created_at": "2019-04-14T00:27:15.000000Z"
  },
  {
    "original": "434,365.04",
    "sale": "428,423.38",
    "cc": "US",
    "language": "English",
    "created_at": "2019-04-13T00:28:18.000000Z"
  },
  {
    "original": "401,200.64",
    "sale": "395,204.86",
    "cc": "US",
    "language": "English",
    "created_at": "2019-04-12T00:28:52.000000Z"
  }
]
```

The site shows no other comparable spikes since the start of data collection in April 2017. Why did this occur?

Comment: It might be related to the BAFTA sales, which ended the day before, but I'm not sure. There didn't seem to be any major game releases around that period. Edit: Might also be related to Twitchcon Europe. Again, not sure.

Comment: notre dame cathedral fire started on that particular week too. although it's unrelated, I'm just gonna put this right here because it might be one of the cause for it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about games or gaming but rather about price trends on a gaming platform.

Comment: @LoreFriendly Thanks for the transparency; could you point me to a Stack Exchange site where this question would be on-topic?

Comment: @SamEstep The comment was from the review queue. I am no expert on this but I would try asking on [Economics.SE](https://economics.stackexchange.com/search?q=trend).

Comment: @LoreFriendly Ok, thanks! It looks like the question would also be off-topic for Economics.SE since it is not a scientific question, and I am not a student/teacher/researcher of economics.